# Uses for Force Touch in the Xcode editor

Tags: macos, xcode, trackpad

Are there any special uses for the Force Touch trackpad on Apple's newer laptops in the Xcode source editor? I have tried to use it for various things but Force Touch always seems to do the same thing as a regular click. It would be cool to be able to force touch a variable and have that open the refactor menu, for instance. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 10 you can use Force Touch inside Interface Builder to select from a list of views and windows under the cursor (i.e. topmost view, its ancestor and all the way to the window):

[image]